# React native android moveTaskToBack?

Tags: android, react-native

Is there any library which has ability like `moveTaskToBack` in React Native?

Previously I use https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-activity-android and it has `moveTaskToBack`. But unfortunately this repo is not active anymore, and since React Native 0.29, it has some internal change which make that library didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure it's what you need, but if you put this in your MainActivity.java class:

```
@Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        // do not call super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() as it will close the app.  Instead lets just put it in the background.
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Then when user press the android back button on the "root" page, the app will go in background instead of being closed.

Source: [background a react-native android app using back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635398/background-a-react-native-android-app-using-back-button/39639286#39639286)

Comment: Unfortunately, latest RN version (0.42) cannot make it work! Do you have any idea for that version? I don't know why previous RN version (0.40) is working, but not on last version. Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712153/moving-a-react-native-android-app-to-the-background-using-back-button-fails-ever. Have you experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation), then navigate to your projects node modules folder and locate the react-native-navigation folder and inside it, follow the path to the NavigationActivity.java:

`/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativenavigation/controllers/NavigationActivity.java.`

In the `NavigationActivity.java` file, you will see the following method at around line 196:

```
@Override
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    if (layout != null && !layout.onBackPressed()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment out the line: `super.onBackPressed()` and add the line: `this.moveTaskToBack(true);`

and thats all! Happy coding