# Call moveTaskToBack() in custom Java React Native module to programmatically move app to background

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, web-applications

I am writing a custom React Native module in Java for Android so I can programmatically move the app into the background using the back button.

I am using the [backHandler built in to React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler), but it only supplies a method to exit the app completely, not move the app to the background.

**When implemented, in my JavaScript code, I will call my native module here:**

```js
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function () {
  /**
   * call native module here
   */
   return true;
  }
```

The recommended way of moving the app to the back using the back navigation button on Android is by adding a method to the `MainActivity` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368201/react-native-android-movetasktoback). But this will cause the app to always to go the background on every back button press. As I want to move the app to the background programmatically, I want to make my own module that I can call at any time.

The difficulty I am facing is how to move this method from `MainActivity` to a custom module.

**The code I have so far is:**

Package:

```java
package com.myApp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MoveAppToBackgroundPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new MoveAppToBackground(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }
}
```

**Module:**

```java
package com.myApp;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;

public class MoveAppToBackground extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MoveAppToBackground";
    }

        private ReactContext mReactContext;

    public MoveAppToBackground(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
                mReactContext = reactContext;
    }

    /* React Methods */
   @ReactMethod
    public void MoveToBackground() {
                Activity activity = mReactContext.getCurrentActivity();
                activity.moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

**MainApplication:**

```java
...
packages.add(new MoveAppToBackgroundPackage());
...
```

**The error I'm getting when I compile the app is:**

> MoveAppToBackgroundPackage is not abstract and does not override abstract method createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext

How can I create this method that I can call in a custom module that moves the app to the background?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I made this work by changing `MoveAppToBackgroundPackage.java` this:

```java
package com.mtApp

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MoveAppToBackgroundPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new MoveAppToBackground(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.asList();
    }
}
```